# Sobrescrever o generator de chave primária do Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

Gostaria de saber por favor se tem como sobrescrever a o `generator` de uma chave primária no Hibernate, no meu caso eu faço uma classe superiora aonde fica o `id`, e as demais estendem dela.

No meu caso essa subclasse, que estende desta que contem a chave primária, vai receber a chave como entrada pelo usuário.

O problema é que após mandar o dado salvar pelo Hibernate, o `sequence` do PostgreSQL insere um valor no banco, que é do `sequence generator`.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão para eu contornar este problema se interferir na estrutura de classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode remover o gerador da entidade.

```java
@Entity 
public class Entidade{
    @Id 
    //@GeneratedValue <-- Remover 
    private Long id;
    ...
```

Outra solução mais simples seria alterar a classe para anotar o método e não a propriedade e trocar o `IdGenerator` para nenhum ( no caso você vai adicionar na mão ).
Neste caso você não precisa ter o trabalho de criar um `IdGenerator` na mão.

```java
@Entity
public class Pai {
    private Long id;

    @Id
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
public class Filho extends Pai {

    @Override
    @Id
    public Long getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }
}
```

Se tiver mesmo que criar um `IdGenerator` recomendo o seguinte:
Estender um existente e alterar sua classe pai para gera o id exclusivamente para a classe que você quer. Mas não recomendo esta solução por causa do acoplamento.

```java
@Entity
public class Pai {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "mygenerator")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "mygenerator",
            strategy = "br.MyGenerator")
    private Long id;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

class MyGenerator extends SequenceGenerator {

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj) {
        if (!obj.getClass().equals(Filho.class)) {
            return super.generate(session, obj);
        }
        return ((Filho) obj).getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara achei algo no sentido de reescrever o próprio `generator` do `Hibernate`, vou verificar pois talvez seja uma solução interessante e irei postar para os colegas como fazer...

Comment: Só uma dúvida, e caso eu tenha implementado o `get` e `set` do Id na classe pai como final?

Comment: Se estiver como final o método do id na classe pai só poderá utilizar a ultima solução.